# How to use support layout_columnWeight in a style?

Tags: android, android-styles, android-gridlayout

I think this snippet from values/styles.xml says it all:

```
<!-- Style for the label above a button -->
<style name="baseLabel">
  <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
  <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
  <item name="android:layout_columnWeight">1</item>
  <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal|fill_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

And a corresponding entry from layout/main.xml might look like:

```
    <TextView
        style="@style/baseLabel" android:text="@string/lr12"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:layout_column="1" />
```

There are no build errors, but the layout_gravity attribute has had no effect. (It works fine if I set it in the layout file: `app:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|fill_horizontal`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `android:layout_gravity` in your style, but `app:layout_gravity` in what you say you're setting in the layout file. Those attributes need to match if you want them to do the same thing, so you should be using `layout_gravity` and `layout_columnWeight` in your style.

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I tried. Unfortunately, that results in a build error: `AAPT: error: style attribute 'app:attr/layout_columnWeight' not found` I'm wondering if there's something I can add to styles.xml to tell it to include symbols from androidx.

Comment: Edited my answer - you would leave out the `app:` part when referencing non-android resources.

Comment: Yep; I just figured it out as well.